# Concrete5 MySQL query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7, concrete5, mysql-5.6

I'm getting following SQL error at Concrete5 CMS, just to give you the background we've recently updated MySQL from 5.6 yo 5.7 and this has started to happen.

I've already tried repairing database but it didn't work

```
mysqlt error: [3065: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'scotnew_c5.u.uDateAdded' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT] in EXECUTE("SELECT DISTINCT u.uID, u.uName FROM Users u left join UserSearchIndexAttributes on (UserSearchIndexAttributes.uID = u.uID) where 1=1 order by uDateAdded desc limit 0,10 ")
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are any updates available for Concrete5?

Comment: This should be fixed in recent concrete5 versions: see https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/pull/5245 and/or https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/pull/5261

Comment: @Michele Locati merged in 2017?